# ScrollIntoView Out only when the text block is out of the user's view (Blast.js)

Tags: javascript, blast.js

How do I make that a text block have a scrollintoview out animation only when that block is hidden from the user's view?

Look at the sample: http://just-text.webflow.io/

At the slightest scrolling, the text block returns to its original position (and plays the animation again). Need this to happen only when this block goes out of sight of the user. I will be grateful for the help

```
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (evt) => {
    const footer = document.getElementById('spans');
  const isInView = isScrolledIntoView(spans);
  if (isInView) {
  console.log('the element is in view and should now execute your code');
    $(function() {

  var words = $('h1').blast({
      delimiter: 'word'
    });

    words.each(function(i) {
      $(this).css({
        position: 'relative',
        top: 150,



      })

        .delay(i * 70)

        .animate({top: '50px'}, 400,); 



    });
  });

  } else {
  console.log('the element is out of view and shouldnt execute your code');
    // TODO: If element is not in view...
  }
})

function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const elemTop = rect.top;
    const elemBottom = rect.bottom;

    return elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
}
```